# Are the following matrix derivations correct? What are the involed rules?

Tags: matrix-calculus

Are the following two derivations correct?

$$
\nabla_{\mathbf{w}}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w} = 2 \mathbf{w}
$$

$$
\nabla_{\mathbf{w}} ||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}||_2^2
=
2\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w})
$$

(I assume that $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ are not functions of $\mathbf{w}$)

What are the rules involed to solve these problems?

Comment: Your second result has a sign error. It should read $2X^T(Xw-y)$.  Then setting $X=I$ and $y=0$ recovers your first result.

Comment: You are right, there is a sign error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$M=Xw-y$$Then use the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) to write the function and its differential 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= M:M \cr
df &= 2\,M:dM \cr
   &= 2\,M:X\,dw \cr
   &= 2\,X^TM:dw \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}:dw\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= 2\,X^TM \cr
   &= 2\,X^T(Xw-y) \cr\cr
}$$
Frobenius products can be rearranged in a variety of ways
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC &= AC^T:B \cr
   &= B^TA:C \cr
   &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
   &= BC:A \cr
   &= {\rm tr}(A^TBC) \cr
}$$
all of which can proved directly, or by using the trace-equivalence and the cyclic property of the trace.